# Displaying spring @controller provided rest services in a jsp file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, web.xml

I currently have a group of rest services provided by Spring 3.1.0 @Controller and wondered if there was any way that I could easily provide a list of the services (links to the restful services) in my index.jsp file. I know reflection is an option but thought spring may have a way to see the services provided by @Controller and allow me to display them.

Comment: You will be more likely to receive (better) answers if you accept some answers from questions you have previously asked.

Comment: @nicholas-hauschild cheers, hadn't know about marking them answered..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specific implementation of the `HandlerMapping` interface that your `DispatcherServlet` is using, you may be able to figure it out from there.

For example, if you are using the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`, there is a method present called [`getUrlMap()`](http://srcrr.org/java/spring/3.1.0/reference/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.html#getUrlMap%28%29), which returns a map of the url path mappings.

Comment: are you referring to the dispatcher in the web.xml ? <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

Comment: I am.  But you should be able to get a hold of your `HandlerMapping` straight from your `ApplicationContext`.  If you are using `@Autowired`, you should be able to just autowire it into the class that will do the url calculation/listing.

Comment: @nicholas-hauschild thanks for your help but can you point me at an example. I'm not familar with this..

Comment: I would start at this link:  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch16s04.html

Comment: thanks. I've had a look but I cannot see how I can tie Spring ApplicationContext into a jsp file. I assume that there is much more to this than i orginally thought.

Answer (score 0):

What nicholas is pointing out is that there are different ways to maps requests. You've to check which HandlerMapping you're using exactly and then see how to get the mapping information it stores via class getters.

Here is an example for Spring MVC 3.1 @Controllers:
https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-31-demo/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc31/endpointdoc